# How to not store a return value in ImmutableJS

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I have some entries in an Immutable `Map`. How can I create a new map, while discarding some entries?

**All Data**

`headers =  ['title', 'url', 'layout', 'modules', 'enabled', 'captcha', 'updated_at', 'contents', 'username', 'excerpt', 'settings'];`

**Expected data**

`headers =  ['title', 'url', 'enabled', 'updated_at', 'contents', 'username', 'excerpt'];`

**Code I have**

```
 columnHeaders = keys.map((key) => {
      if (skipHeaders.includes(key)) {
        return null;
      }
      return key;
    });
```

**This results for the above code:**

```
headers =  ['title', 'url', null, null, 'enabled', null, 'updated_at', 'contents', 'username', 'excerpt', null];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` instead of `map`:

```
columnHeaders = keys.filter((key) => !skipHeaders.includes(key));
```

`filter`, as provided by Immutable, is an immutable operation that will return a new collection excluding the values from the original collection that don't return a truthy value when passed through the filter function